# python re.split() , как распарсить команду?

Tags: python, строки

Необходимо распарсить команду:

***Фир ник Пупкин "Pupkin prod."***

// Фир ник [Аргумент:цель] [Аргумент:ник]

// Кавычки здесь для того чтобы отделить ник от всего остального, так как он с пробелами.

так, чтобы в итоге получилось.

```
['Фир', 'ник', 'Пупкин', 'Pupkin prod.']
```

Помогите пожалуйста, для меня регулярка, это больная тема. =с

Answer (score 5):

Есть более простой и удобный способ, чем регулярные выражения - модуль [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shlex.html) из стандартной библиотеки:

```
import shlex
shlex.split('Фир ник Пупкин "Pupkin prod."')
```

Comment: Спасибо, оно работает. Но немного подумав, я решил упростить и просто ограничил стандартный split до 2 разделений. Но всё равно спасибо!)

Comment: @ЕвгенийСтарцев, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)